# C++11: How to access targets of std::functions with different types?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, function-pointers, std-function

I want to code a minimal multicast delegate class. Its interface consists of the three operators operator() for calling the delegate and operator+=/operator-= for adding/removing callable types like functions, methods, lambdas or functors.

I have trouble to implement operator-= where I need to compare addresses of function targets for removal. Here is what I came up with so far (I use g++ 4.6.3):

```
#include <functional>
#include <list>

template <typename ... EventArgs>
class Event
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void (EventArgs...)> EventHandler;

    Event() = default;
    ~Event() = default;
    Event(const Event &) = delete;
    Event & operator=(const Event &) = delete;

    void operator()(EventArgs... eventArgs)
    {
        for (auto eventHandler : m_eventHandlers)
            eventHandler(eventArgs...);
    }

    Event & operator+=(const EventHandler &eventHandler)
    {
        m_eventHandlers.push_back(eventHandler);
        return *this;
    }

    Event & operator-=(const EventHandler &eventHandler)
    {
        m_eventHandlers.remove_if([&](const EventHandler &_eventHandler)
        {
            return false; // TODO: Compare event handlers
        });

        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::list<EventHandler> m_eventHandlers;
};
```

operator-= works for functions when I substitute the TODO line with the following code:

```
return * eventHandler.template target<void (*)(EventArgs...)>() ==
       *_eventHandler.template target<void (*)(EventArgs...)>();
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
void eventHandler() { /* ... */ }

Event<> event;
event += eventHandler;
event();
event -= eventHandler; // works
```

However, for other callable types it crashes since std::function.target() returns null pointers. Obviously the template doesn't fit anymore so I tried to template Event::operator-= but it does not compile for the most callable types due to "incomplete types":

```
template<typename T>
Event & operator-=(const T &eventHandler)
{
    m_eventHandlers.remove_if([&](const EventHandler &_eventHandler)
    {
        if (_eventHandler.template target<T>() != null_ptr) // <- ERROR
        {
            // ...
        }
    });

    return *this;
}
```

I also tried T* as template parameter for target() but I'm stuck. Is it possible to code a generic operator-= that can correctly compare any callable type?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you commented that you guarantee that the targets will be comparable, you may want to use your own type-erasure solution (that requires the underlying types, i.e. the targets in `std::function` lingo, to model e.g. EqualityComparable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `std::function<>` doesn't support comparison operators `==` and `!=`. [`boost::function` has an explanation for that](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/function/faq.html#id1549884).

One solution is to store the functions in a map or a hash keyed by an integer. Registration would return that integer key. To unregister the key has to be passed, e.g.:

```
typedef int handler_id_t;
handler_id_t add(const EventHandler &eventHandler);
void del(handler_id_t);
```

Comment: +1… although it is disappointing that `function` isn't comparable even when its target is, and that there's no way to code around it, the real problem may not be testing callbacks for equality. If two clients register the exact same method, should it be called once or twice?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, Maxim. However, your suggestion is what I actually want to avoid by using some syntactic sugar that C++11 offers. While std::function doesn't support comparison, the targets should be comparable. At some point I would expect all callable types to boil down to a pointer to executable code just like function pointers. At least I hope so. And therefore it would be great to find a way to correctly call std::function.target() in a generic manner.

Comment: @Potatoswatter It should be called twice then. In my code example you can add eventHandler() twice for example and it is executed twice. operator-= removes all occurrences though. But, one could test if a callback was already added in a more complete event class when the target comparision problem is solved.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin So, the conclusion is that it is not possible in principle since one cannot get pointers to code for all callable types, right? Too bad. Thank you for your answers, guys.

Comment: @JackJohansson: "At some point I would expect all callable types to boil down to a pointer to executable code just like function pointers." That doesn't mean that they're equality-comparable. Just because you have a functor that happens to resolve to the same member function doesn't mean that they store the same *data*. Two functors of the same type would have the same member pointers, but could store different data. They aren't necessarily equal. That's why Boost's signals/slots library exposes a special object that you use to destroy the connection (if you want to).